# Disable breaking code execution on exception

Tags: c#

If i will write something like this:

```
void Code()
{
   Console.WriteLine("a");
   throw new Exception(); //the code will stop executing here
   Console.WriteLine("b");
}
```

the code will stop executing after writing "a" to console. I am wondering, is it possible to execute whole function and then throw an exception? So if the exception will be thrown between Console.WriteLine("a"); and Console.WriteLine("b");, it will stop code execution, but i want the function to be executed fully before throwing an exception

Comment: put a try catch around, store your exception and if at the end of your function there is some exception stored, throw it. Not sure, however if this is really advisable.

Comment: This isn't possible.  What if the code after the exception is thrown depends on the result of something that failed to happen before it?  What you _can_ do is catch any exceptions yourself, run any code that you still want to run within the _exception handler_, then rethrow the exception if appropriate.  I'd suggest some reading about [exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for answers. I really need to stop bending programming logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: No, you cant.
And shouldn't try to bend the programming logics to that way either.
An exception is the indication that something went terribly wrong and the function has to quit without a return value. That is the purpose of the exception, to indicate there was an error running the function and it COULDN'T COMPLETE execution.

```
void Code()
{
   Boolean anyErrors = false;
   Console.WriteLine("a");
   anyErrors = true; // whenever something goes wrong.
   Console.WriteLine("b");
   if(anyErrors)
       throw new Exception("There were errors doing whatever I was trying to.");
}
```

You can also in this case:

```
// will return false if it fails and true if succeeds.
Boolean Code()
{
   Boolean anyErrors = false;
   Console.WriteLine("a");
   anyErrors = true; // whenever something goes wrong.
   Console.WriteLine("b");
   return !anyErrors;
}
```

Logics is the basis of programming, think logical and you won't have to fight the language.

Comment: i also thought about making boolean value. thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2):

Not really suggested at all, but i guess you could do something like this.

```
var errors = new List < Exception > ();
Console.WriteLine("a");
try {
    ErrorThrowingMethod();
} catch (Exception e) {
    errors.Add(e);
}
Console.WriteLine("b");
if (errors.Any()) throw new AggregateException(errors);
```

Comment: Can I suggest you to change it to `if(errors.Any()) throw new AggregateException(errors);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
void Code()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
        throw new Exception(); //the code will stop executing here
        Console.WriteLine("b");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b");
        throw new Exception(e.toString());
    }
}
```

which will do what I think you are trying to achieve in this specific case, but as mentioned, often times it just doesn't make sense to try to continue because of dependency on events beforehand.